# OnClick="createComment();" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a newbie in JS. I'm pressing the button defined as

```
<input type="button" value="Create a Comment" OnClick="createComment();">
```

my script function is

```
function createComment() {
    alert("1")
}
```

when pressing the button the following code won't work but when I change the names to somethingelse it works

```
<input type="button" value="Create a Comment" OnClick="somethingelse();">

function somethingelse() {
    alert("1")
}
```

I've checked multiple times there isn't any createComment name used in the document. I also noticed createComment is used in jquery library but it doesn't seem like a function but I'm not sure what it does.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Parse Testing On Desktop</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My Parse App">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
</head>
```

JQuery

```
// Check if getElementsByTagName("*") returns only elements
support.getElementsByTagName = assert(function( div ) {
    div.appendChild( doc.createComment("") );
    return !div.getElementsByTagName("*").length;
});
```

Is there something special with createComment name or is it jquery and why?

Comment: you should put that on jsfiddle or jsbin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `document.createComment` exists as a special function for the `document` object. It's probably reserved, and thus you wouldn't be able to use it as a function name.

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createComment

Comment: You can get around this by putting it in a namespace

Comment: @loanburger true! I just figured for a simple case for a beginner, easier to just change the name. :)

Comment: shouldn't I write document.createComment? then there should be a namespace over document?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to rename your function, but if you want to use it you could place it in a name space:

```
var myNameSpace = 
{
   createComment:function()
   {
       alert('1');
   }
};
```

Your basically wrapping your JavaScript functions inside a name space object.

Then to call it you reference your function through its namespace in your html.   Change this:

```
<input type="button" value="Create a Comment" OnClick="createComment();">
```

to this:

```
<input type="button" value="Create a Comment" OnClick="JavaScript:myNameSpace.createComment();">
```