# No response after form submission and page just auto reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I use ajax to process the form data submitted.

**HTML FORM:**

```
<div class="well">
<form id='createCommentForm' method='post' onsubmit='createComment();return false;'>
    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name='comment' id='comment'
            placeholder='Please input your comments here ..' ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name='name' id='commenter'
            placeholder='Name of commenter'></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type='text' name='taskId' id='taskId'></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Then I am using the code below to process the form and eventually pass the value back to some place in the same HTML file as where the form is to display.

**JS:**

```
function createComment() {
$("#message").html('');
console.log("am i in here?");
var commenter = $("#commenter").val();
var comment = $("#comment").val();
var taskId = $("#taskId").val();
var input = {};
input.commenterName = commenter;
input.message = comment;
input.taskId = taskId;
var inputStr = JSON.stringify(input);
console.log(input);
inputStr = encodeURIComponent(inputStr);
$.ajax({
    url : "/QueueSystem/admin/CreateCommentServlet?input=" + inputStr,
    method : "GET",
    dataType : 'json',
    error : function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var status = data.status;
        var message = data.message;
        if (status == 1) {
            var comment = message;
            COMMENTS.push(comment);
            console.log(comment);
            var commentId = comment.commentId;
            var message = comment.message;
            var html = '\
                <div class="media">\
                    <div class="media-body">\
                        <h4 class="media-heading">' + comment.commenterName + '\
                            <small>' + comment.modifiedDate + '</small>\
                        </h4>'
                        + message +
                    '</div>\
                </div>';

            $("#comments").append(html);

        } else {
            $("#message").html(message);
        }
    }
});
```

}

My problem is that when I press submit, the page gets auto reload and seems like no data is passed through, or maybe the function `createComment()` is not called at all.  I cannot debug because the page just reload automatically and it is unusual to me.

I have the guess because when I run it, the third line in **JS** does not even show anything on console.

But I test my Servlet by manually input the data in URL, the call is successful. So i suspect that the problem is either in the form or the ajax.

Can anybody give me a hint or suggestion or where my codes possibly went wrong?

Many Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [OnClick="createComment();" doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244859/onclick-createcomment-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createComment is an inbuilt function.

[Reference : developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createComment)

try a different function name.

Comment: Thanks @kcube indeed the inbuilt function is fooling me around! Awww

Answer (score 1):

Change the place where the function is called.If you bind the function call to the button and inside that you prevent the default action the ajax will be done

something like:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="createComment(event);" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

and at the beginning of the function

```
function createComment(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

the preventDefault prevent the normal submit button to send the form as "default" and reload the page. I think that your ajax was not fired because the process start whe the page is reloading and you just can't see the result.

Comment: Thanks for you promt response, but nope, same old problem appear. The page just reload once i hit submit.

Comment: try to change the <button> tag with <a> and remove type="submit"... "btn btn-primary" are classes from bootstrap and they work also with the <a> tag